# Porting GNOME keyboard shortcuts to URXVT

Tags: gnome, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, rxvt

I recently switched from `gnome terminal` to `urxvt`. I am also a heavy `emacs` w. tabs user which uses a lot of key combinations similar to `urxvt` (tab related stuff) like `Shift-Left` and `Shift-Right`. These key-combinations are set for selecting text in `emacs`.

Is there a way to map `ALT-1`, `ALT-2`, `ALT-3` for tabs `1, 2, 3 ..`?

Is there an extension to do that ? Can it be achieved through the `~/.Xdefaults` file ?

Comment: cross posted: http://superuser.com/questions/434678/porting-gnome-keyboard-shortcuts-to-urxvt

Answer (score 1):

I previously have written one and upload it onto my [github](https://github.com/kuantkid/urxvt-utils.git).

However, it may subject to unkown bugs actually. If you find any issues regarding the problem, please kindly leave me a message in this thread or on the github.

You can just copy the `tabbed_enh` file you find in the github to the `urxvt` perl libraries and use `urxvt -pe tabbed_enh` to activate it. Also, use `.Xresources` to configure the keys but remember to use `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` after editing the file.